# How to properly describe actions in Rest Api

Tags: rest

Let's say I have Rest Api like the following:

```
POST /link
GET /link/{id}
etc.
```

I want to create rest endpoint for link activation.How can i properly describe it in terms of Rest Api?

This:

```
POST /link/{id}/activate
```

seems violate the standard

Answer (score 0):

Well Standards is big word. REST is specification though :D

You can use PUT with body that says what is to be changed (as Link already exists, we are updating a link)

example:

```
PUT /link/{id}

{
  ...
  "active": true
}
```